# install package following error show

Tags: git, proxy, tls

[ install fscoiety ]

```
git clone https://github.com/Manisso/fsociety.git
Cloning into 'fsociety'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Manisso/fsociety.git/': 
gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

how can fix it?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes i am use proxy server  @nkn

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a proxy you have to set the global proxy parameters in git.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<your_proxy>:<your_port>
git config --global https.proxy https://<your_proxy>:<your_port>
```

Comment: following error will show            root@devesh:~# git config --global http.proxy http://<172.31.100.27>:<3128>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `3128'     @nKn

Comment: you have to remove the `<` and `>` characters, so: `git config --global http.proxy http://172.31.100.27:3128`